# How to convert a JSON object to a type, converting strings to types, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAIwIZQKZwLxwN7DnAVzQCcAuHPfOASwBNzs4YBPAB1XIHJZjqIBzTnAC+AGkr4ISALYccTNnO4xeAocMpjKrMLAYSa9eS3ZcefQSPFUm1GABs5jE0vNqrB1gQT3qUABaoRs6KXAhgYI5IEJyicLSoAGZIBPYwUAAqYOTJ9mgeNr4A1qhQDAqmcJwQBNIIqMSx8UkpaZnZcAAMIprAGsAucADiYEj2GYqYFPhEDfo2dORu-AZSsksqFr34OnrTVItwywYwdo4bqis2Xj5+gUYqBKi9-YMAkhAwDTr2SF8T7AAPBkAHxTXD4ADaAGkAIw0CBwDIAXXmVBhACYEUiYbDkaicXDkZDOC5OMi4KgAB5fCC0KBVZZCAD8R02Ajg5HCkVQ0RewAGkwAYmACHSAegsB8vsQfn9UBLAS4wIlEChUCCgA):

```
const base = {
  user: {
    id: { type: 'string' },
    name: { type: 'string' }
  },
  post: {
    id: { type: 'string' },
    title: { type: 'string' },
    published: { type: 'boolean', defaultsTo: false },
    likes: { type: 'number', defaultsTo: 0 }
  }
}

type GoalType = {
  user: {
    id: string
    name: string
  }
  post: {
    id: string
    title: string
    published: boolean
  }
}

type InterpolateType<T> = {
  [K1 in T]: {
    [K2 in T[K1]]: T[K1]['type'] extends 'string' ? string : boolean
  }
}

type FoundType = InterpolateType<typeof base>
```

How can I convert the `base` object through `typeof base` to the `GoalType`, as I tried to do with `type FoundType = InterpolateType<typeof base>`?

Comment: can you have nested objects or array types?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mblrEw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: You can have array types by adding a `list: true` on the property object, and a union type (within an array or as a single item) with an array of types, like `type: ['string', 'boolean']`. You can't have nested objects. Nested objects would be like `type: 'user'` or things like that.

Comment: @wonderflame sorry for some reason still that website doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you include the array in the `base` type as well?

Comment: check [this link](https://shorturl.at/ptxEM)

Comment: `['string', 'boolean']` is this supposed to be considered as `[string, boolean]` or `(string | boolean)[]`?

Comment: @wonderflame `(string | boolean)[]`

Comment: Oh wow I was reasonably close, thank you so much, feel free to post the answer!

Comment: should I cover the list case as well then? Because the approach that I proposed will not work for the lists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253802/discussion-between-lance-and-wonderflame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent the compiler from widening the type:

```
const base = {
  user: {
    id: { type: "string" },
    name: { type: "string" },
  },
  post: {
    id: { type: "string" },
    title: { type: "string" },
    published: { type: "boolean", defaultsTo: false },
    likes: { type: "number", defaultsTo: 0 },
    likesArr: { list: "true", type: ["string", "boolean"] },
  },
} as const;
```

We will also need a string to type map type:

```
type StringToType = {
  string: string;
  boolean: boolean;
  number: number;
};
```

To interpolate, we will map through the type and check if the `type` of its property is in the `StringToType`. If it is there, we just return the `StringToType[type]`, otherwise, we check whether the property is a list with `{list: "true", type: readonly unknown[]}`. If the condition is true we pass the elements of `type` to `StringToType` by using `number` as the index to retrieve all the elements in the `type`: `StringToType[T[K][K2]["type"][number] & keyof StringToType]`. We need to intersect with `keyof StringToType` to make sure that we only pass the values that exist in the `StringToType`. Finally, we make the array out of that by appending `[]` at the end. If none of the above conditions are true we just return the `type` itself without any modification.

```
type InterpolateType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [K2 in keyof T[K]]: "type" extends keyof T[K][K2]
      ? T[K][K2]["type"] extends keyof StringToType
        ? StringToType[T[K][K2]["type"]]
        : T[K][K2] extends { list: "true"; type: readonly unknown[] }
        ? StringToType[T[K][K2]["type"][number] & keyof StringToType][]
        : T[K][K2]["type"]
      : T[K][K2];
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
// type Result = {
//     readonly user: {
//         readonly id: string;
//         readonly name: string;
//     };
//     readonly post: {
//         readonly id: string;
//         readonly title: string;
//         readonly published: boolean;
//         readonly likes: number;
//         readonly likesArr: (string | boolean)[];
//     };
// }
type Result = InterpolateType<typeof base>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwgUxgXhgbwFAxgVxQCcAuLXPGASwBMzMYoBPAB2TICJoiqwBzDjAC+AGgp4wCALbssjVrK5Qe-QaIrq8LENHrjqdOczaduvAcLGVGVKABtZDY4rOrL+lvjh2qEABbIhk4KnHAgIA4IYBwiMDTIAGYI+HZQEAAqIGRJdiju1j4A1sgQ9PImMBxg+FJwyEQxcYnJqRlZMAAM+ZRFJQCCRKRyPrqVyvjIjc5kANpKKgKxHGERyFEcALrd6kIwSDCgkFAA3NjYzjAAysrmmekK6OR4rnxkL6d4K5FgZF9rYB8YNVavUyMC6kRTkJTucHgBJMBQeraOwIJH3NgAHnSAD5Hjg8DMANLUMAwYpMEAJGDpDZ6azEgBMpPJyEp1PSxI2dLGCkEyAAHkiwDQIKz2TSuUyNvo8AB+SVEjbSubOTYwQXC0XiqlXG78O4KWWUBXXBaGtgzTlKlUcNXc414MjW5VExlbTXIEVihgjKCccaTY7lWRENY0cB2JgEMCFMAgADuYBmWyEjpgpv1fAtyCtUrdyrtfOV4PqWwAZDrqWbbiAMchlTLrNZnfn3ari8bWzaC4Dodh+2cAPRDkMwABKJRSsAwOBHzbDCAjYCjBGIennzcoi+Xq9obyzp03W5gO8j0ckMgPCyPo+s-ePeDPK+j2lGc7vJ+fe8M72wj4XcNzxsexZD-ADrG-V8vBGAJDD+KJbxPJ8gJfGBelKIEaghJDkKg9CqGKCABiGAAKF4YAAH3gcJvgAShTXDKAfUc0wuScIGnR4ESRIgUTRZB60xZxdUQFAcVOIA)

Comment: How you are quite skilled. Very well done. What is the reason behind needing `const`? Also it should be `list: true` not `list: "true"` :) And what is the reason for the `readonly` in the type def?